# Can Angular 6 and Material display in the dialog not the entire component, but only part of it?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a component and a table view. The same component has a form for adding a new record. I would like to display this form in a dialog, but do not put it in a separate component. It's possible?

Comment: No, it's not. But if you keep the form in separate component, you can use it multiple times in different places. Reusable components in Angular is a usual thing.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question correctly, it is possible. Use a ng-template in your component HTML, which contains what you want to show in the dialog.

```
<ng-template #dialogTemplate>
    <h1 mat-dialog-title>Title</h1>
    <mat-dialog-content>
      Formgroup for adding item goes here
    </mat-dialog-content>
    <mat-dialog-actions>
      <button mat-button [matDialogClose]='true' mat-icon-button><mat-icon>check</mat-icon></button>
      <button mat-button [matDialogClose]='false' mat-icon-button><mat-icon>cancel</mat-icon></button>
    </mat-dialog-actions>
</ng-template>
```

Then, create a ViewChild in your ts-file

```
  @ViewChild('dialogTemplate') dialogTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;
  constructor(private dialog: MatDialog) { }
```

Then, you open the dialogbox by calling the function from your button etc.

```
  open() {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(this.dialogTemplate);

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(answer => {
      if (answer === true) {
         // logic to save your item goes here
      }
    });

  }
```